# Python Linear Programming, Constrain Input to Zero or Range

Tags: python, math, scipy, data-science, linear-programming

In an Linear Program I am minimizing the distance between weighted input vectors and a target vector. I used Scipyto compute values for the weights I need. Currently they are between zero and one, but I'd like them to be zero if they are smaller than .2 for example, so x_i should be 0 or [.2; 1]. I was pointed to mixed integer linear programming but I still can't find any approach for my problem. How can I fix this?

tldr: i want to use (0,0) or (.3,1) as bounds for each x, how do i implement this?

Here is my SciPy code:

```
    # minimize the distance between weighted input vectors and a target vector
def milp_objective_function(weights):
    scaled_matrix = input_matrix * weights[:, np.newaxis] # scale input_matrix columns by weights
    sum_vector = sum(scaled_matrix) # sum weighted_input_matrix columns
    difference_vector = sum_vector - target_vector
    return np.sqrt(difference_vector.dot(difference_vector)) # return the distance between the sum_vector and the target_vector

# sum of weights should equal 100%
def milp_constraint(weights):
    return sum(weights) - 1

def main():
    # bounds should be 0 or [.2; 1] -> mixed integer linear programming?
    weight_bounds = tuple([(0, 1) for i in input_matrix])
    # random guess, will implement later
    initial_guess = milp_guess_weights()
    
    constraint_obj = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': milp_constraint}
    result = minimize(milp_objective_function, x0=initial_guess, bounds=weight_bounds, constraints=constraint_obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables that are in {0} ∪ [L,U] are called **semi-continuous variables**. Advanced MIP solvers have built-in support for these types of variables.

Note that SciPy does not have a MIP solver at all.

I also want to note that if your MIP solver does not support semi-continuous variables you can simulate them with binary variables:

```
 L ⋅ δ(i) ≤ x(i) ≤ U ⋅ δ(i) 
 δ(i) ∈ {0,1}
```